# How to configure the virtual host in apache to let the users access those resources with certain file extensions only?

Tags: apache

How to configure the virtual host in apache to let the users access those resources with certain file extensions only?

Eg. I want users have access to .jpg .png .html files only. How to configure that in the virtual host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the apache directories by allowing access for images folder and deny the access to the others

```
<virtualhost>

 Documentroot /var/www

 Alias /images /path/to/images
 <Directory "path/to/images">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all # allow access to images only
 </Directory>

 <Directory "path/to/apps">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Deny from all
 </Directory>

</virtualhost>
```

Comment: Thanks drabo. Do you know any other solution which can identify the file extensions rather than set accessibility for certain directories?

Comment: that solution exist ,you have to use the mapping files names method. i never used it so i can tell you how it works really.